# PIL can´t open image [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The file and folder exist, but every time I try to start the program I get

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory

```
cover_location = r'C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Test\Cover.png'
cover = Image.open(cover_location).convert("RGB")
```

Comment: `print(os.path.isfile(cover_location))` --- what's output?

Comment: @NasirRiley If you mean the `r` before the string, that's a [raw string literal](https://www.codevscolor.com/python-raw-string).

Comment: This sounds obvious, but is the only conceivable way I could see this problem happening. Have you actually checked to make sure that file exists? If so, please screenshot your file structure including that file path (blur out anything you don't want public) because otherwise there really isn't anything we can do to help.

Comment: Try using `os.path.isfile(cover_location)` to verify that the file exists (and the path is valid).

Comment: Check your path. The format is ok; I don't see any other way this problem could be raised.